# GIT error on ubuntu machine: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git, git-merge

Until today, I was able to push code locally onto my ubuntu test server's git with no problem.

Now, I get this strange error when pushing code.

[Here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2jtiK.png)

I have tried doing a hard reset locally and that did not fix the issue. I also did a git fetch and re-commit / push. That did not fix the issue either.

Any ideas? I have a couple more people that push code to this test server. Something must have gone wrong.

**edit**
I should add that in the error, those pmt/ files, I have not modified locally. Some other team member must have modified and pushed those to the server and now there is this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You have local changes to those files that are not committed. Usually, you want no local uncommitted changes when you perform a merge.

The way to handle this situation is to "stash" the changes:

```
git stash
```

This "stashes" the changes away, cleaning your local working area.
Then perform the merge.  If you want the stashed changes back, do:

```
git stash pop
```